# How do i set patientid format like year/month/1,2,3.. ie 2015/04/1,2,3..?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I want to set patientid format like 2015/04/1,2,3. How can I do it? What datatype should use? After month change, it automatically set to new month like 2015/05/1,2,3.

Comment: You need to give a lot more background to this. It's really not clear what you're asking here - we don't have enough context.

Comment: Today's date is 2015/04. If new patient enters, id should set to 2015/04/01. It should increment 2015/04/02.

Comment: Well today's *date* includes a day as well as a year and month. And we don't know anything about the code involved here. In particular, we'd need to know whether there could be multiple clients etc. Is there any particular reason why you want to allocate IDs like this? You can easily separate the ID from the creation date... why do you want the two together?

Comment: It's client request. They manually enter such entries.

Comment: Well if they're *manually* entering the values, I don't see where your code would come in... Your question is still unclear. And again, you haven't told us anything about the code involved. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Manually entering values in Register. They don't have any software application yet.

Comment: Okay, well you should edit your question to include that information... Along with the rest of the context I asked about.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon that you are missing a lot of context and there are many things you haven't thought of or at least if you have thought of it haven't put it in the question.  So I'm sure this will turn around and bite me but here is an attempt at answering the question.  Since you are on MS SQL 2008, you won't be able to use sequences.

```
// a Sequence table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PatientId](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Junk] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

DECLARE @id INT;

// Insert a junk record to get the next identity value
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
// Store the value
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
// Format your poorly designed PatientId
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));

//Rinse and repeat
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));

TRUNCATE TABLE PatientId


INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO PatientId (Junk) VALUES ('');
SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), GETDATE(),111),7) +'/'+  CAST(@Id AS NVARCHAR(100));
```

Comment: Also as a good developer, you shouldn't always give the customer what they want as they don't always know what they are asking for.  :>